# how to solve Invalid Email error while trying to send emails to multiple recipients in google app script

Tags: javascript, email

```
I am unable to understand why I am getting invalid Email when I am trying to send emails to multiple recipients ...column 5 in my sheet contains the list of all recipients .  

  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){//data contains the sheet data 
         // the last row which has to be updated 
        var lastUpdatedRow = updateSheet.getLastRow()+1;
        var row = data[i];
        var deviceModel = row[0];
        var OS = row[1];
        var name = row[4];
        var recipientsTO = row[5];  
        var location = row[6]
          MailApp.sendEmail(recipientsTO,subject, message, { htmlBody: html});
```

row[5]-contains all the mail addresses
Able to send for a single recipient in the row[5] but unable to read the next available recipients address

Comment: please provide sample data in var  row[5]

Comment: row[5] contains emails address-like abc@domain.com

Comment: myself issused solved

Comment: just post correct ans as answer and make it correct to close thread